# Call Vue store action through browser console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store

I'm trying to create a webapp using **VUE Vite** with a `router` and `store`. The getter function in the vue file works fine. I have access to the `chatMessages` stored in the **store.js** file.

My problem is that I need to call the `addMessage` Action from the **store.js** file in the dev console using the browser.

**Question:** How could I archive this?

On older vue versions it would be done the following way using the **main.js** file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex';


Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: function (h) { return h(App) },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
            'showLoading',
        ]),

        ...mapActions([
            'addNotification',
        ]),
    },
}).$mount('#app');
export default app;
```

**Current vue3 chat.vue file:**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Chat',
  data: function() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      chatMessages: 'chatMessageList',
    }),
  }
}
</script>
```

**Current vue3 store.js file:**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
    state: {
        chatMessages: {
            list: [
                { type: "a", message: "test" }
            ]
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        addMessage(state, { type, message }) {
            state.chatMessages.list.push({ type: type, message: message });
        }
    },
    actions: {
        addMessage({ commit }, { type, message }) {
            commit('addMessage', { type, message });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        chatMessageList(state, getters) {
            return state.chatMessages.list;
        }
    }
})
```

**Current vue3 main.js file:**

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import {createApp} from "vue";
import router from "./router/index.js";
import store from "./store/store";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";

window.app = createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount('#app');
```

**EDIT:** I tested it the following way and I can call app.addMessage from the dev console but now the router wont work.

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import {createApp} from "vue";
import router from "./router/index.js";
import store from "./store/store";
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";

window.app = createApp({
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'addMessage',
        ]),
    }
}).use(router).use(store).mount('#app');
```

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem. If you need to expose store, assign it to window the same way as app

Comment: The problem is that i want to call the store.js actions from the console.

Comment: Added a edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`store` is already available in this scope and can be exposed the same way as `app`:

```
window.store = store;
```

It can be used in console the same way as in an app:

```
store.dispatch(...)
```

Comment: so i could simply use store.dispatch to call the addMessage function?

Comment: Yes, the same way as you'd usually do with vuex store

Comment: seems to work just got a issue now that I shows undefined values.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the store to the window object seems like a great approach, where you can easily then call it like in domiatorov's answer.

Another approach is:

```
var store = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).find(e => e.__vue_app__).__vue_app__.config.globalProperties.$store;

var actions = store._actions;

actions.addMessage[0]('mytype', 'mymessage');
```

The first part queries the body for an element containing `__vue_app__` and will return your instance. In there, you can access `config.globalProperties.$store` to return your store object.

Comment: That's a nice trick for debugging without devtools involved

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply assign the store to the window object.

But do it from a top level single file component, the very first that is using the store and not in the setup to make sure the store got everything loaded.

Providing you have something like `App.vue`:

In `setup()` you would assign:

`window.vueStore = store;`

and use it from the console calling `window.vueStore`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that it's not necessary to do this in a component, a store is available prior to app instantiation